# Set Selected Value from array using select2 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-select2

I have array in javascript like this

`var array =  ["Impression", "Clicks", "CTR", "CVR", "CPC", "CPM", "CPA"]`

I want to **set selected text** in select2 from one of my array but getting confused.

select2 code:

```js
$('.params_1').select2({
  placeholder: "Impression",
  allowClear: false,
  data: array,
  initSelection: true
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected="selected">text</option>
  <option>text</option>
</select>
```

I'm using `placeholder :"impression"` but that not selected, it just label in my select option.

Comment: There is no class on select element. <select class='params_1'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want have some option to be selected from array, your html should contain that option.

For example- if you want to set "Impression" to be selected, change your html to following-

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Impression</option>
</select>
```

And if you want to provide your options with some `value`, you should change your Array to be an array of objects. For more details, please check [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array) link.